# How to differentiate between a search query and an URL?

Tags: android, string, url, search, browser

I am trying to make an android browser, I have a `searchView`.

Right now I am providing a google search Result for whatever the user enters in the `SearchView`, But I want to differentiate between a search query and a URL, (for example if user enters "facebook.com" user should be directed to "http://www.facebook.com").

I tried to check if the query is followed by ".com" but it will not be helpful when user is trying to access ".net" ".in" or any domain followed by anything else than ".com".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(yourQueryOrUrl).matches();
```

it will return true if url is valid Url and false if is just a query and not a url. It will handle your cases for .in and .net domains

Comment: thanks for the response, I wanted to ask if I need to pass "facebook.com" or i need to add 'http://www.facebook.com' before the query?

Comment: just "facebook.com" as string only. Like Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher("facebook.com").matches(); 
No need to add extra "" on the query just pass the query

Comment: thanks, it works fine if user enters ''facebook.com" but if user adds www. in front of it, the webpage does not load because of double "www". Is there a way so that it can be detected how much user have entered. 
                 
This is my code after verifying if it is a URL.
                web1.loadUrl("http:// www."+search_q);

Comment: dont put the extra "http:// www.". You can you this for your use case

if(!search_q.startsWith("www.")&& !search_q.startsWith("http://")){
  search_q = "www."+search_q;
}
if(!search_q.startsWith("http://")){
  search_q = "http://"+search_q;
}